# Заменить все placeholder через регулярное выражение

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Eсть строка `dasdasd {{asd}} asd asas dsad {{qw1}} d asdasdasdasd`.
Мне надо заменить все `{{any text}}` на пустую строку, как сделать с помощью регулярных выражений?

Если использовать `\{\{.*\}\}` то выделяется строка `{{asd}} asd asas dsad {{qw1}}`, как модифицировать regex чтобы выделялись только `{{asd}}` и `{{qw1}}`?

Comment: Так `\{\{.*?\}\}`

Comment: @Visman, спасибо, работает!

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ оставил пользователь [Visman](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186083/visman) в комментариях:

```
\{\{.*?\}\}
```

Comment: Или `\{\{[^}]*(?:\}(?!\})[^}]*)*\}\}`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, опишете в чем отличее вашего варианта

Comment: Если кратко, то 1) не требует модификатора `Pattern.DOTALL` для захвата символов конца строк и 2) при работе с большими текстами работает гораздо быстрее.

Answer (score 0):

Регулярное выражение

```
String pat = "\\{\\{.*?}}";
```

работает в Java для нахождения всех вхождений подстрок типа `{{...}}`, так как:

- `\{\{` - `{{`
- `.*?`  - любые 0+ символов, отличных от символа переноса строки, как можно меньше (так как `*?` - ленивый квантификатор)
- `}}` - `}}`.

См. [Java-демо](http://ideone.com/uY2Kgz):

```
String s = "dasdasd {{asd}} asd asas dsad {{qw1}} d asdasdasdasd";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\{\\{.*?}}").matcher(s);
List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
while(m.find()) {
    res.add(m.group());
}
System.out.println(res);
// =>  [{{asd}}, {{qw1}}]
```

Чтобы получить строки без фигурных скобок, испольуйте *захватывающие группы*:

```
String pat = "\\{\\{(.*?)}}";
                    ^   ^
```

А в `res.add(m.group(1));` укажите номер группы - 1.

Если между `{{` и `}}` могут быть символы переноса строки, нужно передать в конструктор флаг `Pattern.DOTALL` (или `(?s)`), благодаря которому `.` сможет "отлавливать" символ `\n`:

```
String pat = "(?s)\\{\\{.*?}}";
```

См. [Java-демо](http://ideone.com/KHT0bt).

В Java регулярные выражения с `.*?` в шаблоне часто вызывают проблемы с производительностью, если входной текст очень большой. В таком случае есть смысл "развернуть" регулярное выражение таким образом, чтобы отрезки текста между `{{`  / `}}` находились быстрее:

```
String pat = "\\{\\{[^}]*(?:}(?!})[^}]*)*}}";
```

Тут `.*?` заменено на `[^}]*(?:}(?!})[^}]*)*`:

- `[^}]*` - 0+ символов, отличных от `}`
- `(?:}(?!})[^}]*)*` - 0 и более последовательностей следующих шаблонов:

  - `}(?!})` - `}`, после которого нет `}`
  - `[^}]*` - 0+ символов, отличных от `}`

См. [ещё одно Java-демо](http://ideone.com/KKmgoy).